# Apply and Iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

This is the input data:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],
              'Group':['G1','G3','G2','G1','G2','G3','G1','G2','G3'],
              'Value':[15,21,14,8,17,22,11,13,15]})


data=data.sort_values('Value',ascending=False)
```

What I expect is to create a column called "Weight" which gives 1 or 0 to each entry depending on other columns:

1. I sort the "Value" Columns
2. For each "Group", I give a budget. If the sum exceeds the budget, all remaining entries will get a "Weight" of 0

Expected Output:

```
data_out=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],
              'Group':['G1','G3','G2','G1','G2','G3','G1','G2','G3'],
              'Value':[15,21,14,8,17,22,11,13,15],
              'Weight':[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]})
```

An illustrative example of how we get this weight is:

the threshold for G1 is 27 (see below dictionary), a is 15, which is smaller than 27, it is assigned a weight of 1, next g is 11, so the total is 15+11=26 < 27, so b will be also assigned as a weight of 1. d is 8, which will exceed the budget of 27 if it is added, so it get a weight of 0. Same logic applies to the G2 and G3.

```
threshold_dic={'G1':27,'G2':32,'G3':25}

initial_dic={'G1':0,'G2':0,'G3':0}

def f(row):
    
    if initial_dic[row['Group']]<= threshold_dic[row['Group']]:
        
        row['Weight']=1
        
    else:
        
        row['Weight']=0
        
    initial_dic[row['Group']]+=row['Value']
    
    return row

data.apply(f,axis=0)
```

It throws me an error. I also tried this one:

```
for i in data.iterrows():
    
    if initial_dic[row['Group']]<= threshold_dic[row['Group']]:
        
        row['Weight']=1
        
    else:
        
        row['Weight']=0
        
    initial_dic[row['Group']]+=row['Value']
```

Still not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a loop/iterrows, use vectorial code.

Compute the [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) or your values (cumulated sum per group), then compare to the threshold for each group (assigned with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)). If the sum is ≤ threshold ([`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)), then assign `1`, else `0`.

```
data['Weight'] = (data
 .groupby('Group')['Value'].cumsum()
 .le(data['Group'].map(threshold_dic))
 .astype(int)
)
```

Output:

```
  Name Group  Value  Weight
5    f    G3     22       1
1    b    G3     21       0
4    e    G2     17       1
0    a    G1     15       1
8    i    G3     15       0
2    c    G2     14       1
7    h    G2     13       0
6    g    G1     11       1
3    d    G1      8       0
```

Intermediates:

```
  Name Group  Value  cumsum  threshold  cumsum ≤ threshold  Weight
5    f    G3     22      22         25                True       1
1    b    G3     21      43         25               False       0
4    e    G2     17      17         32                True       1
0    a    G1     15      15         27                True       1
8    i    G3     15      58         25               False       0
2    c    G2     14      31         32                True       1
7    h    G2     13      44         32               False       0
6    g    G1     11      26         27                True       1
3    d    G1      8      34         27               False       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very elegant solution. Meanwhile, could you please direct me or simply illustrate when and how I should use iterrows() and apply(axis=0) respectively. This has been a recurring issue for me.

Comment: You should probably almost **never** use `iterrows`. In very rare cases in which efficiency is not relevant this might help (e.g, iterating over rows for plotting). Other than that, I really never had to use it.